# Passing Events Back to the Dialog's Host when host is a RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a list of cards with a button on each one. When clicked it opens a dialog and allows the user to select an integer value. When the dialogue is closed I want the value to be passed back to the card so some text can be updated.

This is the extension of the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` `OnClick` event for the button:

```java
public class CardEvent extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements SetReminderDialogFragment.SetReminderDialogListener {
        ...
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager f = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
        SetReminderDialogFragment d = new SetReminderDialogFragment();
        ...
        d.show(f, "reminder");
    }
```

These are the callbacks that update the card, also in `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` extension (nothing in them yet):

```
    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) { }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNeutralClick(DialogFragment dialog) { }
    ...
}
```

Then there is the dialog fragment:

```
public class SetReminderDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
   @Override

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    builder.setView(view)
            ...
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //Do Nothing - Just Dismiss
                }
            });
            if (i != null)
            {
                builder.setNeutralButton("Remove", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ...                            
Listener.onDialogNeutralClick(SetReminderDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ...                                    
Listener.onDialogPositiveClick(SetReminderDialogFragment.this);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                builder.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ...
Listener.onDialogPositiveClick(SetReminderDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                });
            }
    return builder.create();
}
```

This is supposed to implement the callback functionality, as per [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents):

```
    public interface SetReminderDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNeutralClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

SetReminderDialogListener Listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        Listener = (SetReminderDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException f) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement SetReminderDialogListener");
    }

}
```

However, the `activity` of course does not implement the callback interface. I can't use `setTargetFragment` either, since it is not an extension of `Fragment`. How can I pass back this value to the card that called the dialog, or at least inform it that the dialog has been dismissed (preferably with a parameter of which button has been pressed), so it can update its contents?

Many Thanks

Comment: Already calling `onDialogNeutralClick` and `onDialogPositiveClick` method when Dialog closed ? then what problem getting?